# How to extract a pattern from a makefile string variable

Tags: makefile

In a Makefile, I have a variable `DPDK_CUSTOM_REPO_VERSION` which is defined as follows:

```
DPDK_CUSTOM_REPO_VERSION="dpdk-19.08-devel"
```

How to Extract `19.08` from above string into another variable `DPDK_VERSION`?

Comment: Could you not do it the other way around? `DPDK_VERSION = 19.08` `DPDK_CUSTOM_REPO_VERSION = dpdk-$(DPDK_VERSION)-devel`

Comment: Unfortunately no, I get DPDK_CUSTOM_REPO_VERSION from external config and I need to extract version from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string processing abilities of the `make`-command are somewhat limited, but you can try the following:

Replace all occurrences of `-` with space:

```
$(subst -, ,$(DPDK_CUSTOM_REPO_VERSION)
```

resulting in `dpdk 19.08 devel` and take the second word:

```
$(word 2, $(subst -, ,$(DPDK_CUSTOM_REPO_VERSION)))
```

This should yield the correct result, if the pattern doesn't change significantly.
Put it together to:

```
DPDK_CUSTOM_REPO_VERSION="dpdk-19.08-devel"
DPDK_VERSION=$(word 2,$(subst -, ,$(DPDK_CUSTOM_REPO_VERSION)))

test:
        echo $(DPDK_VERSION)
```

Comment: Thanks, Pattern isn't expected to change. Worked like a charm!